# Novel(s) about sidhe/fae intersecting modern day, possibly young adult with Native American themes

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I am remembering a novel (and I'm pretty sure it might have been a trilogy) from the late 80's to the 90's. I'm not sure the actual publishing date, that's when I came across it/them, and they were softcover. They might have been young adult, but at that time they were not marketed in the bookstore as such.

To avoid false trails, it wasn't really modern day urban fantasy or anything like Shadowrun.

What I can remember is a young adult main character (I think male) observing sidhe on horseback, kind of phasing into out reality in a forested area. The Pacific Northwest might have been a location, but I'm not positive. The setting didn't seem urban at all.

I'm getting a sense that the main character may have had some Native American heritage. My memories are really faded.

Trees were an important lore / plot point. I remember the author explaining how magic interacted with oak, ash, and elm—and that ash was some sort of super conduit.

Does this ring a bell with anybody?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I feel like such a jerk. I signed up on this site because I have not been able to figure out what these books were for a decade. I sign up here, take a break, and find it 50 minutes later.

It was a series of books about a kid named David Sullivan. The first one was called *Windmaster's Bane* and it was by Tom Deitz. The young man doesn't seem like he's native American, but the author used some NA lore as well as Celtic myth. And it wasn't the Pacific Northwest, but it was in the mountainous forested region of Georgia.

Sorry to waste your time! I can't believe I finally figured it out!

Comment: Sometimes the site works like magic. You would never have found it if you hadn't posted the question here.

Comment: Now that you've posted the question and answer, the next person who's looking for the same books will be able to find them by searching this site.

Comment: If it's any comfort I did exactly the same thing https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/33485/5297